# How are credentials stored and encrypted in Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14?

Tags: security, password

How does Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14 store and encrypt it's user credentials?

I couldn’t finy anything in the documentation, knowledge base nor on the web on how credentials (local users) are stored by Nexus OSS 2.14.

The only hint was a release note of 2.5 about introducing salted hashes.

Where in the data dir are credentials saved? What algorithms/ciphers are used to encrypt them?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be about how a software supply chain management system stores user credentials and not related to running your own website.

Comment: I opened this question in webapplications because the description of webapplications is "Q&A for power users of web applications" and that's what I am.

They closed it because it's a "development question" what's totally not the case...

webapplications doesn't care about it's own description and says "For managing and maintaining your own hosted web application please ask on Pro Webmasters"

The supply chain is complety irrelevant for this question. Nexus is a web application I host.

So I came here to get my question closed... again. Where to post it now?

@StephenOstermiller

Comment: If you have a website running this software, then it should be on-topic here.  I've re-opened.    You may not an answer here though.  I doubt that any of our regulars have experience with it.

Comment: Have you tried asking https://www.sonatype.com/contactus?

Comment: @Steve They sent us to the sonatype community where I didn't get any answer.

Comment: @Stephen yes, I have a website running this software.